# JavaScript Loop return the current index

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar

I want to make a PHP mailer, and want to add a progress bar using JS.
So I have a list of emails (textarea) (my problem is with the progressbar),  here's the code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//to get every mail by line in textarea
var textarea = tt.replace("\r\n", "\n");
var textarea = textarea.replace("\r", "\n");
var textarea = textarea.split("\n");


var indice=0;
for(var i=0;i<count(textarea);i++){
var line = textarea[i];
var indice= indice+100/count(textarea);

$('#waiting').load('sent.php',{ln:line,indc:indice}, function(){
var finale = $('#waiting').text(); //return the current value of indice
$('#progressbar').css({ "width" : finale+"%"});
setTimeout('#waiting', 1000);
});
}
</script>
```

For example if I have a list with  4 lines = 100/4 = 25. So in every loop it will send the current index, first index 25% second (25+100/4=50%)... 100%.
MY PROBLEM : is the loop print directly the final index = 100%,she doesn't return the current index in every loop, and when i add a timer it doesn't work... i have a problem with my function i need a help please for my progress bar please :) my progress bar need to get every index in every loop not quickly,just one by one please i need a help

Answer (score 0):

That is beacuse

```
var indice=0;
```

is decalred outside the loop and still you are defining again inside loop

```
var indice= indice+100/count(textarea);
```

Try

```
indice= indice+100/count(textarea);
```

and this may solve problem.
Regards

Comment: the loop still return just the final index and not every index of every loop, so my progress bar when i click on the button it's go to 100% directely. and not print every current index and wait 1000ms to pass to the other index .... :(

Comment: Would you please setup fiddle so that i can take a look at issue ?

Comment: in the beginin indice =0. the list contient 4line for exemple so the loop turn 4 time. the first time:0+100/4=25. i send this value "25" to the sent page,the sent page return this value if all is ok, so if all is ok it will return 25 and the progress bar will go to 25%, the second time indice=25 = 25+100/4=50,..... and like that still to the end 100%. the problem is my code doesn't wait to show you every indice for every loop, it show you directely the final indice 100% and when i add a timer it dosen't work :( ... i need a help for my progress bar

Comment: please i need a help, if some one know how i can print every loop index one by one, and not directely the finale one, an idea to stop this function with a timer or any thing please